# Nest.js handling errors for HttpService

Tags: rxjs, axios, nestjs

I'm trying to test NestJS's built in HttpService (which is based on Axios). I'm having trouble testing error/exception states though. In my test suite I have:

```
let client: SomeClearingFirmClient;

  const mockConfigService = {
    get: jest.fn((type) => {
      switch(type) {
        case 'someApiBaseUrl': {
          return 'http://example.com'
        }
        case 'someAddAccountEndpoint': {
          return '/ClientAccounts/Add';
        }
        case 'someApiKey': {
          return 'some-api-key';
        }

        default:
          return 'test';
      }
    }),
  };

  const successfulAdd: AxiosResponse = {
    data: {
      batchNo: '39cba402-bfa9-424c-b265-1c98204df7ea',
      warning: '',
    },
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: {},
    config: {},
  };

  const failAddAuth: AxiosError = {
    code: '401',
    config: {},
    name: '',
    message: 'Not Authorized',
  }

  const mockHttpService = {
    post: jest.fn(),
    get: jest.fn(),
  }

  it('Handles a failure', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    mockHttpService.post = jest.fn(() => of(failAddAuth));

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ConfigService,
          useValue: mockConfigService,
        },
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: mockHttpService,
        },
        SomeClearingFirmClient,
      ],
    }).compile();

    client = module.get<SomeClearingFirmClient>(SomeClearingFirmClient);

    const payload = new SomeClearingPayload();
    try {
      await client.addAccount(payload);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('e', e);
    }
  });
```

And my implementation is:

```
async addAccount(payload: any): Promise<SomeAddResponse> {
    const addAccountEndpoint = this.configService.get('api.someAddAccountEndpoint');
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${addAccountEndpoint}?apiKey=${this.apiKey}`;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    };

    const response = this.httpService.post(url, payload, config)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res.data;
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);
        }),
      ).toPromise().catch(e => {
        throw new HttpException(e.message, e.code);
      });

    return response;
  }
```

Regardless of whether I use Observables or Promises, I can't get anything to catch. 4xx level errors sail on through as a success. I feel like I remember Axios adding some sort of config option to reject/send an Observable error to subscribers on failures... but I could be imagining that. Am I doing something wrong in my test harness? The other StackOverflow posts I've seen seem to say that piping through `catchError` should do the trick, but my errors are going through the `map` operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `mockHttpService` seems to return no error, but a value:

```js
mockHttpService.post = jest.fn(() => of(failAddAuth));
```

What `of(failAddAuth)` does is to emit a value(`failAddAuth`) and then complete.

That's why the `catchError` from `this.httpService.post(url, payload, config)` will never be reached, because no errors occur.

In order to make sure that `catchError` is hit, the observable returned by `post()` must emit an **error notification**.

You could try this:

```js
// Something to comply with `HttpException`'s arguments
const err = { response: 'resp', status: '4xx' };

mockHttpService.post = jest.fn(() => throwError(err));
```

`throwError(err)` is the same as `new Observable(s => s.error(err))`([Source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/throwError.ts#L71)).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The issue was in the mock itself. Thanks!

Comment: How come `expect(mockHttpService.post).toHaveBeenCalled();` fails the test? Is there something special we must do to make it observe/know that it was called?